# Buffer flushing not working for printf function

Tags: c, fflush

> Coming from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1716621/1461017

I want to print separate points (dots, "."), one at a time on the same line, under control of a `for` loop:

```
for (i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    printf(".");
    sleep(1);
}
printf("\n");
```

But the output only goes to screen after the final "\n", and I want each one to display immediately upon printing, so as to serve as progress indicators.  I expected that `fflush()`ing the standard output on each loop iteration would produce that result, but this does not work (results are only shown on screen after the execution of the for loop):

```
for (i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    printf(".");
    sleep(1);
    fflush(stdout);
}
printf("\n");
```

I have furthermore tested all of these approaches, both in and out of the loop, with no success:

```
fflush(stdout);
fflush(NULL);
setbuf(stdout,NULL);
```

What is going on here, and how can I solve it?

**Further Data:**

- **Ubuntu Linux** v16 as operating system.
- **Code::Blocks** as IDE.
- Problem only happens when running on Bash **command line**. Working OK inside the IDE.
- Tested on Ubuntu **Linux** (same that runs the IDE) and **FreeBSD** (via cross compiling with clang).

Comment: try `sleep(1);
    fflush(stdout);` --> `fflush(stdout);sleep(1);`  If this does not help,  I suspect your compiler is non-compliant.

Comment: Why are you emphasizing random words?

Comment: What is the difference between "tested" and "**tested**"?

Comment: @chux I think it's not compiler but the IDE console. Eclipse has these issues for years.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Good point.  Sopalajo de Arrierez, Try code outside IDE.

Comment: To add on @EugeneSh. IMHO IDEs try to optimise their console output by only managing lines not characters.

Comment: @AndrewHenle , I was emphasizing (now I see my question have been changed) the words that I consider are the core of the issue, so the text become more readable. Deleting my emphasizing could end by discouraging me on keeping this habit, that I think pretends to help others reading me.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  : "tested" when bold, like the original bolded words on my question, were helping to make a quick read of the text. Simple "plain" and boring texts are not so confortable to read.

Comment: So, @EugeneSh. , maybe you could point some link to the correct emphasizing rules ?

Comment: @chux : (correcting myself) the problem only happens when running on `Bash` command line. Tested on Ubuntu Linux (same that runs the IDE) and FreeBSD v10 (via cross compiling with `clang`). Updated the question to reflect.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez It sounds like your _program_ is performing as desired.  It is the shell (bash) that is buffering output.

Comment: @chux: confirmed that `fflush(stdout);sleep(1);` makes no difference. Tested on both BSD and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Well... a stupid issue, but I think I should write it down anyway, because someone could have it too:

The **problem** was: on the command-line testing, I **appended** some `| more` in order to stop the screen dumping. So the `stdout` buffer was altered by the piping `|` command.

Say my program binary file was named `dotting`. I called it by typing:

```
dotting | more
```

I hope this ridiculous case could help anyone in a future.